# Negative entries on the diagonal of the variance covariance matrix after MLE estimation of a Pearson Type 4 distribution

Tags: r, distributions, maximum-likelihood, hessian

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a Pearson Type 4 distribution using maximum likelihood. At the estimated values some of the diagonal entries of the variance-covariance matrix are not positive.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Take the following `R` example (I draw partially from the package `PearsonDS`):

The density is

```
dpearson4 <- function (x, m, nu, location, scale, log = FALSE) 
{
        k <- 2* Re(gsl::lngamma_complex(m + (nu/2) *(0+1i) ) ) - lgamma(m) - log(scale) - lgamma(m - 0.5) - lgamma(0.5)

        return(exp(k - m * log(1 + ((x - location)/scale)^2) - nu * atan((x - location)/scale)))

}
```

while the log-likelihood function can be written as:

```
LL <- function(theta, x){
  m <- theta[1]
  nu <- theta[2]
  location <- theta[3]
  scale <- theta[4]

  tmp <- -sum(log(dpearson4(x, m, nu, location, scale, log = FALSE)))

  if (is.na(tmp)) +Inf else tmp
  return(sum(tmp))
}
```

I generate a dummy dataset as follows (I use the `rpearson` function in the `PearsonDS` package)

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rpearsonIV(1000, 5, 5, 6, 6)
```

I start my search setting seeds using the built in ML function in `PearsonDS`

```
param <- pearsonFitML(x)[-1]
```

which gives,

```
>param
$m
[1] 5.383121

$nu
[1] 5.779641

$location
[1] 6.259333

$scale
[1] 6.041999
```

However, this function does not return the Hessian so to estimate the variance-covariance matrix I run the maximum likelihood algorithm using the output of `pearsonFitML` as seeds

```
control.list <- list(maxit = 100000, factr=1e-12)#, fnscale = 1000)
  fit <- optim(par = param, 
               fn = LL, 
               hessian = TRUE, 
               method = "L-BFGS-B",
               lower = c(0.51,-Inf,-Inf,0.1),
               upper = c(Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf),
               control = control.list,
               x = x)
```

The output is:

```
solve(-fit$hessian)
                 m        nu   location      scale
m        -1.830761 -3.290973 -1.2920021 -1.0307047
nu       -3.290973 -6.941729 -2.8530122 -1.6134873
location -1.292002 -2.853012 -1.1963544 -0.6144129
scale    -1.030705 -1.613487 -0.6144129 -0.6599055
qr(fit$hessian)$rank
[1] 4
fit$par
       m       nu location    scale 
5.383123 5.779641 6.259333 6.042000
```

The standard errors of the parameters are (approximately) equal to the square root of the diagonal entry of the inverse of the negative Hessian at the true value. Does this invalidate my estimate or is there an issue somewhere else? Thank you.

Comment: I can still estimate the variance covariance matrix by bootstrap. Yet, I'm wondering whether my estimates are valid.

Comment: I think because you're minmizing the negative log-likelihood, the standard errors are calculated by `sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian)))`. As a check, I redid the maximum likelihood estimation using the `bbmle` package and got the same standard errors. See also [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2004-February/046272.html).

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I can give you credit if you copy paste this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're minimizing the negative log-likelihood, the standard errors are calculated by `sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian)))`. Here is a short check using the `bbmle` package. First the original:

```
library(PearsonDS)
library(bbmle)

dpearson4 <- function (x, m, nu, location, scale) 
{
  k <- 2* Re(gsl::lngamma_complex(m + (nu/2) *(0+1i) ) ) - lgamma(m) - log(scale) - lgamma(m - 0.5) - lgamma(0.5)

  return(exp(k - m * log(1 + ((x - location)/scale)^2) - nu * atan((x - location)/scale)))

}

LL <- function(theta, x){
  m <- theta[1]
  nu <- theta[2]
  location <- theta[3]
  scale <- theta[4]

  tmp <- -sum(log(dpearson4(x, m, nu, location, scale)))

  if (is.na(tmp)) +Inf else tmp
  return(tmp)
}

set.seed(123)
x <- rpearsonIV(1000, 5, 5, 6, 6)

control.list <- list(maxit = 100000, factr=1e-12, fnscale = 1)

fit <- optim(par = c(2, 2, 2, 2), 
             fn = LL, 
             hessian = TRUE, 
             method = "L-BFGS-B",
             lower = c(0.51,-Inf,-Inf,0.1),
             upper = c(Inf,Inf,Inf,Inf),
             control = control.list,
             x = x)

sqrt(diag(solve(fit$hessian)))

[1] 1.3530814 2.6347706 1.0937976 0.8123553
```

Now using `bbmle`:

```
LL2 <- function(theta){

  tmp <- -sum(dpearsonIV(x, m = theta[1], nu = theta[2], location = theta[3], scale = theta[4], log = TRUE))
  if (is.na(tmp)) 
    +Inf
  else tmp
}

parnames(LL2) <- c("m", "nu", "location", "scale")

fit2 <- bbmle::mle2(minuslogl = LL2
            , start = c(m = 2, nu = 2, location = 2, scale = 2)
            , method = "L-BFGS-B"
            , lower = c(a = 0.5, b = -Inf, c = -Inf, d = 0.1)
            , upper = c(theta = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf))
))

summary(fit2)

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
m         5.38541    1.35359  3.9786 6.932e-05 ***
nu        5.78422    2.63658  2.1938   0.02825 *  
location  6.26131    1.09416  5.7225 1.050e-08 ***
scale     6.04340    0.81239  7.4391 1.014e-13 ***
```

The standard errors are practically identical. Conveniently, the `bbmle` package can calculate confidence intervals based on profile likelihood:

```
confint(fit2)

            2.5 %    97.5 %
m        3.581845 10.276182
nu       2.680049 19.171886
location 4.695503 10.009925
scale    4.729774  8.033266
```

Comment: Is the `BB` optimization procedure always better than the classic `optim`?

Comment: Do you mean `bblme` and `mle2`? It's basically just a wrapper that makes it more convenient. Internally, it also uses `optim` but offers other optimizers such as `nlminb`, `optimx` etc.

Comment: Oh, I confused it with the `BB` optimization package. Thanks a lot!